# getopt() parsing mode not working

Tags: c, linux, unix, glibc

According to the manpage, getopt() has three different parsing mode

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so
>          that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.  Two other modes
>          are also implemented.  If the first character of optstring is '+' or
>          the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, then option
>          processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.  If
>          the first character of optstring is '-', then each nonoption argv-
>          element is handled as if it were the argument of an option with
>          character code 1.  (This is used by programs that were written to
>          expect options and other argv-elements in any order and that care
>          about the ordering of the two.)  The special argument "--" forces an
>          end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.

On my Centos 7, it seems that '+'/'-' signs failed to switch the parsing mode, they all give the same results, and here is my testing code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parse(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstr)
{
    printf("opterr: %d optstr: %s optargs: ", opterr, optstr);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int opt = -1;
    optind = 1;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1) {
        printf("optind: %d optopt: %d "
               "optarg: %s opt: %c\n",
               optind, optopt, optarg, (char)opt);
    }

    printf("unparsed: ");
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void nonoption()
{
    const char *optstr = "ab";
    char *argv[] = {"", "-a", "hello", "-b", "world"};
    parse(5, argv, optstr);
}

void posix_nonoption()
{
    const char *optstr = "+ab";
    char *argv[] = {"", "-a", "hello", "-b", "world"};
    parse(5, argv, optstr);
}

void nonoption1()
{
    const char *optstr = "-ab";
    char *argv[] = {"", "-a", "hello", "-b", "world"};
    parse(5, argv, optstr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    nonoption();
    posix_nonoption();
    nonoption1();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
opterr: 1 optstr: ab optargs:  -a hello -b world
optind: 2 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: a
optind: 4 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: b
unparsed: hello world
opterr: 1 optstr: +ab optargs:  -a hello -b world
optind: 2 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: a
optind: 4 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: b
unparsed: hello world
opterr: 1 optstr: -ab optargs:  -a hello -b world
optind: 2 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: a
optind: 4 optopt: 0 optarg: (null) opt: b
unparsed: hello world
```

Comment: Try calling only one function and not all three in one program.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Why do you think this is a problem about debugging? I already dumped all the data and steps in the parse function. Maybe it's a good time to learn how to *READ*

Comment: @Osiris Thanks for your advice, I have already solved this problem by reading the source code of glibc though. I will write it down later.

Comment: @YiZhenfei You can also look at my answer, your problem is indeed described in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `getopt` [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) you will find this paragraph:

> A program that scans multiple argument vectors, or rescans the same
>          vector more than once, and wants to make use of GNU extensions such
>          as '+' and '-' at the start of optstring, or changes the value of
>          POSIXLY_CORRECT between scans, must reinitialize getopt() by
>          resetting optind to 0, rather than the traditional value of 1.
>          (Resetting to 0 forces the invocation of an internal initialization
>          routine that rechecks POSIXLY_CORRECT and checks for GNU extensions
>          in optstring.)

You have to set `optind` to `0` in function `parse`, then it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a shame that I missed this point in the manual. I actually tried reset optind to 0 before, but the behaviour is that getopt will reset it to 1, thus I thought that maybe 1 is the right value to use.